# Communicating between Mysql php and Objective c

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode

Currently I am developing an application in Xcode using objective c where you can post something and view other peoples posts. It sends this post to a database, and then on another view controller that post would be shown for any user of the app to see. I know how to post and receive data from the database, however my problem is displaying the data. I would like to display an un-editable textview or something along that line for each post on the page that displays the posts. I am not sure how to create one for every time there is a new post and how to make the page scroll. I know this is a lot to ask, however if possible please help me out. If you are confused about how I am trying to display the data, you could look at edmodo's mobile app. I am trying to display the posts in that manner. Once again, thank you and please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to use UITableView or UITableViewController and need to create Custom UITableViewCell as per your need to display Post.

A Custom UITableViewCell consist of UITextView and by setting its *Editable* property in Attribute Inspector or programmatically `self.yourTextView.editable = No;` you can make UITextView Non-editable.
Also check following links:

1. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/
2. http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Can I use a regular view controller and add a table view onto it instead of using a table view controller? If so how would i set that up because when I link the delegate and data source to itself the app crashes

Comment: Sure, you can use ViewController instead of TableViewController and can add TableView onto it.
After adding TableView onto ViewController set ViewController as DataSource & Delegate of TableView. for that select TableView and in right side pane(Inspector pane) of Xcode select last one Connections inspector. It will show DataSource & Delegate options. now drag from DataSource to ViewController i.e yellow point in Storyboard or document outline. do same for Delegate.
http://imgur.com/LRqQ3Xj&NeJdSEB
also refer below link.
http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/